# How to automatically open show / hide javascript tab and re-hide on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have some tabs which show hidden information when clicked. But as they are now, they will open but only close when a new tab is clicked. If possible could I get help with these two issues:

**1-** I want to make the tab close again when you click it a second time.

**2-** I have links set up to open the page where each section starts. Is there anyway I can make the tab open automatically when that link is clicked?

I appreciate the help.

Edited to show the full code I have now:

```js
$('.drop a').click(function() {
  var $content = $(this).parent().next().toggle();

  //HIDE THIS LINE IF YOU DO NOT WANT TO HIDE OTHER TABS ON CLICK
 $('.droptab').not($content).hide();
});
```

```css
.droptab {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="child-page">

<a class="anchor" id="<?php echo $child->post_title; ?>"></a>        

<h2 class="child-title drop"><a><?php echo $child->post_title; ?><span class="down-arrow"><img src="down-arrow.png" /></span></a></h2>

<div class="droptab">

    <div class="description"><?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $child->post_content); ?></div>

    <aside class="sidebar">

        <div class="info">

            <div class="more-but">

                <a href="<?php the_field( 'get_more_url', $child->ID ); ?>" class="button left"><span class="caption">Get More Info</span></a>

            </div>

        </div>
                  
    </aside>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div><!-- .droptab -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use toggle instead of hide show.

The toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected elements.

**Hide this line "$('.droptab').not($content).hide();" IF YOU DO NOT WANT TO HIDE OTHER TABS ON CLICK**

```js
$('.drop a').click(function() {
  var $content = $(this).parent().next().toggle();

  //HIDE THIS LINE IF YOU DO NOT WANT TO HIDE OTHER TABS ON CLICK
  $('.droptab').not($content).hide();
});

//ADD THIS LINE IF YOU WANT TO OPEN FIRST TAB BY DEFAULT ON PAGE LOAD
$('.droptab').first().toggle();
```

```css
.droptab {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdowntabs">
  <a class="anchor" id="main-tab"></a> 
  <h2 class="drop">
    <a>MAIN TITLE</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="droptab">
    <p>MAIN TITLE CONTENT</p>
  </div>
  <a class="anchor" id="second-tab"></a> 
  <h2 class="drop">
    <a>SECOND TITLE</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="droptab">
    <p>SECOND TITLE CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work as OP would like it to work. Did you even test it?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek updated my answser. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Still not desired effect. It should close all opened dropdowns and toggle the clicked one

Comment: so when I click main title, It should open and if any other tab is open then those opened tabs should close?

Comment: Done, I have modified my answer. I don't think he needs that but anyway. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I am having a problem with this. It only seems to work on the second item in the list.
The rest will no longer open.
The list is dynamically generated by wordpress posts if this makes a difference.

Comment: @Jason If you my snippet code above in my answer it works correctly for both tabs. If your code is different than your supplied code in your question, then you need to give us your code so we can see what is going wrong. We cannot help you without seeing what you are doing. You might be giving wrong ID to elems or same ID to elems or something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Hey24sheep Sorry for the delay. Ok sorry about that. I updated my code to show what it is at right now.
I want to ideally have one open when you go to the page. But then I need them to toggle. When you click one it opens and then it will close on re-click or it will close when another is clicked.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jason try my code. If I understood your question right, My given code will work.

Comment: @Jason I have updated my code just see it now. It address both your point 1 and 2 for point 2 just add this line     $('.droptab').first().toggle(); . Accept it as answer if it helped you and upvote.

Comment: @Hey24Sheep Thanks. I had to put the code under instead of above cause it was still only selecting certain divs for some reason, but it works great as I needed it now.
Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it helped u.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toogle` instead for the current link and hide the others:

```
$('.drop a').click(function() {
  var content = $(this).parent().next();
  $('.droptab').not(content).hide(200);
  $(content).toggle(200);
});
```

**Working snippet**

```js
$('.drop a').click(function() {
  var content = $(this).parent().next();
  $('.droptab').not(content).hide(200);
  $(content).toggle(200);
});
```

```css
.droptab {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdowntabs">
  <a class="anchor" id="main-tab"></a> 
  <h2 class="drop">
    <a>MAIN TITLE</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="droptab">
    <p>MAIN TITLE CONTENT</p>
  </div>
  <a class="anchor" id="second-tab"></a> 
  <h2 class="drop">
    <a>SECOND TITLE</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="droptab">
    <p>SECOND TITLE CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```